# Rails | How to create a non-ASCII spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rspec

The code

**welcomes_spec.rb**:

```
...
describe "GET /welcomes" do
  it "Should render main page" do
    visit root_path
    page.should have_content(t("popular_photos"))
  end
end
...
```

**ru.yml**

```
...
ru:
  hello: "Hello world"
  default_page_title: "Test_page_title"
  main_page: "Главная"
  popular_photos:  !NON ASCII SYMBOLS HERE!
```

after `$rake spec` leads the error:

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_content(t("popular_photos"))
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `t' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_5::Nested_1:0xba77028>
```

I am newbie and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace:

```
page.should have_content(t("popular_photos"))
```

with:

```
page.should have_content(I18n.translate("popular_photos"))
```